# Error when taking a subset of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary Retweets containing tweets information. The data structure of a tweet is like this:

```
[{'retweet_count': 338,
  'user': {'description': 'description1.',
   'followers_count': 582,
   'screen_name': 'screen_name1'}
 }
]
```

I want to take only the screen_name of the user and corresponding description into a new dict. Make this into a dict like this:

```
{'screen_name1': 'description1',
 'screen_name2': 'description2',
 'screen_name3': 'description3'
}
```

Here is my code:

```
user_list = []
for retweet in Retweets:
    user_list.append(retweet["user"]["screen_name"])
    final_dict = {key: retweet["user"]["description"] for key in user_list}

print(final_dict)
```

However, the descriptions of all users are the description of the last user. Like this:

```
{'screen_name1': 'description3',
 'screen_name2': 'description3',
 'screen_name3': 'description3'
}
```

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `final_dict` in your second `for` loop. That being said, you don't need that at all. You can simply use a dictionary comprehension:

```
final_dict = {d["user"]["screen_name"]: d["user"]["description"] 
              for d in Retweets}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in one loop only

```
tweets = {}
for retweet in Retweets:
    tweets[retweet["user"]["screen_name"]] = retweet["user"]["description"]
print(tweets)
```

Comment: Agreed. But this was a simple way to show OP where he went wrong in his implementation

Comment: @Abhinav Indeed. It helps me to understand. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

You should put both the key and value in the dict comprehension

```
final_dict = {retweet["user"]["screen_name"]: retweet["user"]["description"] for retweet in Retweets}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, the descriptions of all users are the description of the last user. Like this:

Well yes, consider what your code is doing:

```py
for retweet in Retweets:
    final_dict = {key: retweet["user"]["description"] for key in user_list}
```

id the same as

```py
for retweet in Retweets:
    final_dict = {}
    for key in user_list:
        final_dict[key] = retweet['user']['description']
```

So for each "retweet", you set the dict to mapping every entry in user_list to the RT's user's description.

Meaning you'll first create a dict mapping every screen name to the description of the first user, throw it away, re-create one mapping every screen name to the description of the second user, throw it away, ... until the last.

Since the screen names and descriptions are in the same place, you can just create the final dict correctly in one shot: instead of just extracting the `screen_name`, you can extract *both* screen name and description in the initial loop and create your dict immediately.